# Set margin (indent) based on counter value in CSS

Tags: css

I'm wondering whether it is possible to set the element `margin-left` based on the value of a counter, using CSS3.

In other words, having a HTML like this:

```
<section>A</section>
<section>B</section>
<section>C</section>
```

have first block with a `margin-left: 0em`, second one with `1em` and so on.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
section
{
    counter-increment: sect-indent;
    margin-left: calc(counter(sect-indent) * 1em);
}
```

But it seems that `calc()` doesn't support getting counter values.

Is such a thing possible using CSS3? I'm not interested in solutions involving ECMAScript.

Comment: I'd take an educated guess and say that it isn't possible. Also, isn't nesting the elements possible?

Comment: @Madara Uchiha: Correct, this isn't possible using `calc()` or counters. It has to be done manually or with some other workaround.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: everything is possible but nesting sections isn't semantically correct.

Comment: @MichałGórny--[nesting sections is perfectly fine](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#headings-and-sections), it depends on the content of the sections as to whether it is correct in a particular application. If your sections are subsections of each other (which your indention desire would seem to indicate), then that is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @ScottS: I was referring to this particular context. They're not subsections; it's just an intended visual effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For a Small Set

If you are dealing with a small set of `section` elements next to each other (as your sample shows), then using the adjacent sibling selector (or `nth-of-type` if only CSS3 support is desired) will [get you what you want without counting](http://jsfiddle.net/nNvv4/). However, probably much more than about five elements and the css could get too cumbersome, so if you are looking at this for hundreds of elements, it is not practical.

```
section { margin-left: 0}
section + section {margin-left: 1em}
section + section + section {margin-left: 2em}
```

Comment: Well, I have used `:nth-of-type` for now but I was mostly wondering if there can be a more general solution.

Answer (score 10):

It only works inside the `content` property, not like a variable the way you are thinking of it. If you view it in DevTools or the like, it's not an integer. You'd still see `counter(myCounter)` in there.

"In CSS 2.1, the values of counters can only be referred to from the 'content' property." [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#counter)

Answer (score 3):

For single-line (or otherwise same-height) items you can use a following hack:

```css
section::before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  height: 1.5em; /* a bit more than line height */
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section>A</section>
<section>B</section>
<section>C</section>
<section>D</section>
<section>E</section>
```