# CSS - Use counter() number as property's value

Tags: css

Say I want to increment the `margin-top` of an element according to it's index, using a `counter()` increment. Something like:

```
div {
    margin-top: calc(counter(myCounter) * 10px);
}
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, but I couldn't find any info if it somehow can be used. Neither found something that stated it can't be done, so I wondered...

Since counters are essentially variables mantained by css, is there any way I can use a CSS counter number as the value of a property?

**EDIT**

The supposed duplicate ([Set margin (indent) based on counter value in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430686/set-margin-indent-based-on-counter-value-in-css)) does not provide an answer whether it is or isn't possible, and why. It simply suggests another approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It only works inside the `content` property, not like a variable the way you are thinking of it. If you view it in DevTools or the like, it's not an integer. You'd still see `counter(myCounter)` in there.

"In CSS 2.1, the values of counters can only be referred to from the 'content' property." [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#counter)