# How to indent and line break at the same time in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I know that I can use `<br>` for a simple line break. I also know that I can add indentation by adding styling to a `<p style="margin-left:12px">`.

*Now* I have a problem, which is that **`<p>`** breaks two lines, it is almost like inserting `<br><br>`.

I cannot apply *styling* to `<br>` and also am unable to figure out how to prevent the *double* line break from `<p>`.

Is there something like an element *that does not* **break lines** or similar? No matter what element I add to *apply styling*, they have that double line break, e.g. `div`.

### The Look

#### What I want

```
some text
  some other text
    even more text
```

#### What I was able to achieve

This is what I get using three `<p>` with *`margin-left`* styling:

```
some text

  some other text

    even more text
```

This is what I can achieve with `br`:

```
some text
some other text
even more text
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So you want to create element which won't cause line to break?

Comment: overflow-x=scroll ?

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek I thought the question was clear, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using span elements with `float: left; clear: both;` and then use whatever margin-left you want.

Comment: That did it, thank you. I did not know how to make use of `span` before.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this trick to achieve your goal

```css
span{
display:block;
text-indent:12px;
}
span samp{
display:block;
text-indent:24px;
font-family:initial;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some text
  <span>
    Some other text
    <samp>Some other text</samp>
  </span>
  
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<p>` (paragraph element) is a block-level element. This means, on default it will be positioned in a new row.

That's why you see a double linebreak.

So therefor, use inline elements like `<span>` to move the text to the right.

```html
<p>some text<br/>
    <span style='margin-left:12px'>some other text</span><br/>
    <span style='margin-left:24px'>some more text</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting margins (`margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, most importantly) from `p` elements make them act like lines of text one below another and then use of `<br>` creates single linebreak. However if you want to add `margin-left` based on position of given `p` you can't do this without any SCSS or hard coding values for child number 1, 2, 3 and so on. Other posts on SO about same problem:

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918665/is-there-any-way-to-increment-a-css-value-depending-on-nth-child-variable), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508144/use-nth-child-as-css-variable), [post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989708/is-it-possible-to-use-the-nth-child-value-as-a-parameter-in-a-property-and-how/29852869).

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>test test test test test test test test test</p>
<br>
<p>test test test test test test test test test</p>
<br>
<p>test test test test test test test test test</p>
<br>
<p>test test test test test test test test test</p>
```