# Avoid multiple uls to create a "diagonal" list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a slanted/diagonal list, but want to avoid having several nested uls, is there a way to do this, here is the code I have so far:

```html
<ul className={style.steps}>
  <li>
    <p className={style.step}>Lorem</p>
    <ul className={style.steps}>
      <li>
        <p className={style.step}>Ipsum</p>
        <ul className={style.steps}>
          <li>
            <p className={style.step}>dolor</p>
            <ul className={style.steps}>
              <li>
                <p className={style.step}>sit</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are the number of items fixed in your list or they can change?

Comment: How are you generating this HTML? Can you add data attributes to the `li` elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nth-of-type vs nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set margin (indent) based on counter value in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430686/set-margin-indent-based-on-counter-value-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can update how the code outputs, you don't need nth-selectors, especially if the list is dynamic and changes length, you can use CSS vars.

You can set a default value using `:root`, then you can add the custom property value on each li element `--index: number`. You can change the CSS var on the element to whatever you need.

```css
:root {
  --margin-value: 10px;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-left: calc(var(--index) * var(--margin-value));
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="--index: 1">One</li>
  <li style="--index: 2">Two</li>
  <li style="--index: 3">Three</li>
  <li style="--index: 4">Four</li>
  <li style="--index: 5">Five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:nth-child` selector would allow you to set different spacing rules on different `<li>`s within a single list.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
  <li>sit</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not use the javascript tag, but it could be handy here , so not really an answer but another approach.

Demo below:

```js
var elMargin = 0;
for (let e of document.getElementsByClassName('indent')) {
  elMargin = elMargin + 1;
  e.style.marginLeft = elMargin + 'em';
}
```

```css
ul {counter-reset:lis}
li:before{counter-increment:lis;content:counter(lis);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="indent"></li>
  <li class="indent"></li>
  <li class="indent"></li>
  <li class="indent"></li>
  <li class="indent"></li>
  <li class="indent"></li>
  <li class="indent"></li>
</ul>
```